# How to integrate a (feedback-)link into my Office add-in to the corresponding Microsoft AppSource entry?

Tags: office-js, appsource

Since my add-in is not yet officially listed in Microsoft AppSource I don't have a link to the add-in in MS AppSource.
But as long as my link (currently points to https://store.office.com) does not link to the correct target, the MS test team won't accept my add-in. :(

So, I somehow need to have the chance to look into the future or is there another way?
I assume so, otherwise it would be a never-ending story ;)

Comment: Can you clarify which link you referring to? Support links must be a dedicated web page or an app/company page on a social media platform and Privacy links must be a valid privacy statement relating to your app/add-in and/or your Service. A link to the add-in listing wouldn't meet the criteria for either of these link types.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms I'm thinking of a link directly to the reviews area in Microsoft AppSource (e.g. https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi/692481d2-a35a-4715-97b8-7d1919289db0?src=office&tab=Reviews).
Imho it would make sense to integrate a "feedback"-link to this target, since this is the most logical place to give feedback to an app (here: add-in), right?
What I wanted to do is showing a link (when the functionality of my add-in is done successfully) saying "Your feedback"...

Comment: Maybe I called the "feedback"-link wrong?
It might be possible you rather use the word "review" for it? Sorry, if it's so.
To make you understand what I'm thinking of is what Dean (Slawson) mentioned in his video (https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/Office-Add-Ins-Best-Practices-and-Guidelines-Marketing-and-GTM).
Pls see especially 1:44 when saying "Ask customers to rate and review from inside the add-in".

Comment: Not sure why I received a "-1".
Can someone please explain why the "office-store feedback" exists (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-UX-Design-Patterns-Code/blob/master/templates/feedback/office-store/feedback.html) while my add-in is rejected due to a feedback link to the office store?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviews are generally generated directly from users, via a link sent by automated email. Users who download an app or add-in from AppSource are sent an email approx. 7 days after download containing a link to review the app/add-in if they wish.

If you wish to add a review link into the app/add-in itself, you will need to wait until the app/add-in has been approved, in order to know the WA ID which is created on publishing and required in order to format your review link.

The link to leave a review should be in the format 'https://store.office.com/writereview.aspx?assetid=WAxxxxxxxx' where WAxxxxxxxx is the WA ID generated once your add-in is approved to AppSource. 
This WA ID is not available until your add-in is approved. The WA ID is available from the URL of your add-in listing on AppSource

Comment: Great and thanks a bunch for the answer!
So, I just have to inform the testing guys when they review my add-in that I'll update the Office Store Link as soon as the add-in is approved.